# Mocking Node Module Imported In React Component With Jest + Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am attempting to test a React Component with Jest and Enzyme, but my test fails to run because it seems to be having trouble with a specific node module. The module that is breaking the test is actually imported from a component that sits inside the one I am trying to test.

**Here is the hierarchy:**

- Insights

  - BuildOnScrollHelper (*this is where the node module is imported*).

**When I run this test:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Insights } from '../../containers/Insights';
import insightsMockData from '../../mocks/data/insights';

describe('Insights Container', () => {
  let cmp;

  beforeEach(() => {
    cmp = shallow(
      <Insights
        {...insightsMockData}
        loadReports={jest.fn()}
        fetchGraph={jest.fn()}
      />,
    );
  });

  it('does stuff', () => {
    console.log(cmp.debug());
  });
});
```

**I get this error from Jest in the console:**

[image]

If I go into my **Insights** React Component and comment out the **BuildOnScrollHelper** component(*and its import statement*) the test runs perfectly fine.

**I had two ideas:**

1. I don't even need to mock the node module, perhaps I could just mock **BuildOnScrollHelper** itself? For this test I don't care about **BuildOnScrollHelpers** functionality at all.
2. I will have to mock the node module.

Does anyone know how I would go about this in a manner that is considered good practice? I have spent a few hours trying to hunt down solutions to this, but still can't get my test to work.

Ideally I would like an answer that provides some code examples, and not just a link to a piece of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) out.

> **Mocking Node modules**
>
> If the module you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: lodash), the
>   mock should be placed in the **mocks** directory adjacent to
>   node_modules (unless you configured roots to point to a folder other
>   than the project root) and will be automatically mocked. There's no
>   need to explicitly call jest.mock('module_name').
>
> Scoped modules can be mocked by creating a file in a directory
>   structure that matches the name of the scoped module. For example, to
>   mock a scoped module called @scope/project-name, create a file at
>   **mocks**/@scope/project-name.js, creating the @scope/ directory accordingly.

Comment: Already tried this and I keep getting an error that says, "you are trying to import a function after the jest environment has been torn down."

Comment: The files have some interweaving going on so, i am going to need to post a few code snippets to show exactly what's going on.

Comment: Did you manage to get the mock for a component within a node_module. I am also facing the same issue.